# USING CASE TO ASSIGN VALUES

Tags: sql, oracle

Im getting below error when creating the below trigger: Any clue how to solve it?

13 32 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem then  <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like

```
create or replace trigger "CONVEYANCE_REQUEST_T3"
BEFORE
insert or update on "CONVEYANCE_REQUEST"
for each row
begin

CASE 
when :NEW.REGULAR_TRAVEL_MODE = '2 WHEELER' THEN
 BEGIN
     CASE
         when :NEW.WAY_TYPE = 'ONE WAY' THEN 
              SELECT RATE_PER_KM * :NEW.REGULAR_DISTANCE_ONEWAY * 1 INTO  :NEW.REGULAR_AMOUNT FROM CONVEYANCE_RATE WHERE TRAVEL_MODE = :NEW.REGULAR_TRAVEL_MODE;
         WHEN :NEW.WAY_TYPE ='TWO WAY' THEN
              SELECT RATE_PER_KM * :NEW.REGULAR_DISTANCE_ONEWAY * 2 INTO :NEW.REGULAR_AMOUNT FROM CONVEYANCE_RATE WHERE TRAVEL_MODE = :NEW.REGULAR_TRAVEL_MODE;
     END CASE;
 END;
when :NEW.REGULAR_TRAVEL_MODE WHEN = '4 WHEELER' THEN
 BEGIN
     CASE
        when :NEW.WAY_TYPE = 'ONE WAY' THEN 
              SELECT RATE_PER_KM * :NEW.REGULAR_DISTANCE_ONEWAY * 1 INTO :NEW.REGULAR_AMOUNT FROM CONVEYANCE_RATE WHERE TRAVEL_MODE = :NEW.REGULAR_TRAVEL_MODE;
         WHEN :NEW.WAY_TYPE ='TWO WAY' THEN
              SELECT RATE_PER_KM * :NEW.REGULAR_DISTANCE_ONEWAY * 2 INTO   :NEW.REGULAR_AMOUNT FROM CONVEYANCE_RATE WHERE TRAVEL_MODE = :NEW.REGULAR_TRAVEL_MODE;
     END CASE;
 END;


END CASE;
END;
```

Comment: What exactly is this trigger supposed to do?

Comment: Your amount of END's is screwed up, for a start. You need one END for each CASE statement, and one END for the BEGIN of the trigger's code block. You probably have a BEGIN you don't need among your CASE statements, too. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php

Comment: Your constructions for the CASE statement look wrong to me. Have a look at the link in my comment above for correctly written ones and syntax outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `some_variable := (SELECT some_column FROM ...)`.  Instead, do all of the calculation inside the query and assign the result using `SELECT ... INTO`.  For example, here's how to do the first assignment to `:NEW.REGULAR_AMOUNT`:

```
SELECT RATE_PER_KM * :NEW.REGULAR_DISTANCE_ONEWAY * 1
  INTO :NEW.REGULAR_AMOUNT
  FROM CONVEYANCE_RATE ...
```

I'll leave it up to you to deal with the remaining cases.

Comment: thanks luke. have done as you have shown. errors has reduced now to only 1. but still not able to figure out how to sort it out. I have shared the new code above. Thanks for your support.

Comment: thanks a lot luke. i figured it out . an extra 'when' screwed it up.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is additional WHEN in following line..

```
when :NEW.REGULAR_TRAVEL_MODE WHEN = '4 WHEELER' THEN
```

try with below code

```
when :NEW.REGULAR_TRAVEL_MODE = '4 WHEELER' THEN
```